# Imageview visibility by dynamic databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I want an imageView to be visible if internet connectivity is unavailable, invisible otherwise. How do I achieve this by dynamic data-binding ?

Lets say, I have a function in my activity `checkInternetConnectivity` that returns true if internet connectivity is available. How do I dynamically bind the return value with the visibility of the imageView ?

Comment: Can u post what you have tried?

Comment: Currently, I have an imageView whose initial visibility is set by checking internet connectivity which is very trivial. I can declare a NetworkStateBroadcastReceiver to control the visibility of the imageView, which I will eventually resort to if data-binding cannot be enforced.

Comment: I have used data binding with AngularJS, but not with android.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom attribute for the ImageView and invoke the method dynamically using Binding Adapter .

**XML**

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:internet="@{imageUrl}"/>
```

**JAVA code**

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:internet")
public static void loadImage(ImageView view, String url) {
  if(checkInternetConnectivity()) {
     // load the image
  }
  else {
     // setting the view visibility to invisible
     view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }
}
```