# How to bind custom object to spinner layout using databinding library?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, android-databinding

I wish to bind my object to spinner row layout by android databinding library. [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946893/android-custom-spinner-layout) and [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625249/android-how-to-bind-spinner-to-custom-object-list) not explained how I can use databinding and how to bind multiple fields (not only one string) of data object.

My data object looks like:

```
class Data{
    public final String imageUri;
    public final String title;
    public final int totalCount;
}
```

Layout I wish looks as:

```
<!-- horisontal orientation -->
<LinearLayout>
    <!-- Icon -->
    <ImageView/>

    <!-- Title -->
    <TextView/>

    <!-- TotalCount -->
    <TextView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and how it bind I don't know...

Comment: If android databinding library not support this functionality, interesting look at another ways of binding custom data object and layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap your entire layout in **layout** tag to use Data Binding.This way you can assign the Model to your View So this should be your layout.

```
<layout>
   <data>
     <variable name="data" type="your.packagename.Data">
     </variable> 
   </data>
   <!-- horisontal orientation -->
   <LinearLayout>
     <!-- Icon -->
     <ImageView
       android:src="@{data.imageUri}"/>

     <!-- Title -->
     <TextView
       android:text="@{data.title}"/>

     <!-- TotalCount -->
     <TextView
       android:text="@{data.totalCount}"/>

  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Lets assume your are using Activity to show the Spinner & your layout name is **custom_spinner.xml** . Then here is how you set the data to layout. After setting the Spinner Adapter, here is what you need to do

```
Data data; // Data object
CustomSpinnerBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner);
binding.setData(data);
```

This should be your custom Adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CustomSpinnerBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner);
    binding.setData(dataList.get(position)); // you should pass dataList as an argument in Custom Adapter constructor
}
```

Comment: can you explain: who set _data variable_ of layout? I want to understand this mechanism

Comment: I understand how to bind data to layout, but question is: how to use binding mechanism with spinner adapter and set of data objects?

Comment: You share your SpinnerAdapter

Comment: For strings I use _ArrayAdapter_. Which adapter used for databindings  I don't understand

Comment: Then how will you inflate your custom spinner layout for each spinner item without using your custom adapter. Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8116756/5173119

Comment: You suggest just override _getView_ and _getDropDownView_ methods of adapter to inflate databinding layout?

Comment: You might also need some custom binding adapters or better attributes for setting the image url or the count text.

Comment: @tynn Yeah exactly , http://stackoverflow.com/a/41214783/5173119 similar to this , where we can load the image.